# Jenkins: Run grunt command in windows command from Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, command-line, gruntjs

I am running Jenkins with many jobs. I am using Groovy so that I can have one script to work on both Windows and iOS slaves. I have gotten grunt commands to run on iOS but have been unsuccessful on Windows.

Working for iOS:

```
println environment["grunt_build"].execute().text
```

I have tried the following for Windows slave:

1. `println "grunt build".execute().text`
2. `println "cmd.exe grunt build".execute().text`
3. `println "cmd.exe /c:/ grunt build".execute().text`
4. `println environment["grunt_build"].execute().text`

The ones I have tried on Windows either skips the command or hangs with a loading spinner four hours and never finishes. (If it is even executing).